# Dependency Injection in storage provider class, which is used by a logger

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, ninject

Im writing my custom logger and injecting a log storage. I need to log requests to this storage. The problem is that this will be a circular reference between logger and storage. Is there a way to provide loose coupling in this case?

Smth like this:

```
public interface ILogger{
    void Log(String msg);
}

public interface IStorage{
    void Save(String msg);
}

public class MyLogger:ILogger{

    private IStorage _storage;

    public MyLogger(IStorage storage){
        _storage = storage;
    }

    public void Log(String msg){
        _storage.Save(msg);
    }
}

public class MyStorage:IStorage{

    private ILogger _log;

    public MyStorage(ILogger logger){
        _log = logger
    }

    public void Save(String msg){
        _log.Log(msg);
        //....
        //send msg to a database like SQL, MongoDB, Cassandra or anything
    }

}

public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<MyLogger>();
        Kernel.Bind<IStorage>().To<MyStorage>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can solve the problem by property injection but how would you expect it to work? Call to `IStorage.Save` or `ILogger.Log` will blow up with `StackOverflowException` due to circular calls.

Comment: property injection is not gonna help - i tried it. And btw properties are initialized after ctor. That is exactly the problem - I dont know who to solve circular reference in this design

Comment: Property injection will help if you can remove constructor dependency in one of the classes. But `StackOverflowException` is for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are doing this? You have a storage class to persist logging messages, but it not only stores messages, but also logs again? You lost me.